# Handle exception in spring boot inner transaction method

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, transactions, spring-transactions

In the Spring Boot project, we have two classes named A and B, each of which has a Transactional method inside.
We inject class B into A and call its method.
Now, if the method in class B gets an error during execution, what will happen to that error???
Because in any situation spring gives the message
"transaction silently rollback"
and the exception thrown in class B method is completely ignored and cannot be catch.

How can I catch and display the message thrown in class B's method???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using `@Transactional` without any Propogation value i.e. default is `REQUIRED`.
In this case when B throws an Exception, the transaction is rolled back (even that executed in class A method. You can catch this exception for logging purpose using try catch in method of class B, but should be thrown again, ideally. Or you can do so using AOP. If you want to commit changes done in A but not in B, in case of exception, you can use `Propogation.REQUIRES_NEW`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.     
   Can you please explain a little more about how to do this with AOP.

Comment: https://www.techgeeknext.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-aop-after-throwing-example